# C++ Writing to file vector of byte

Tags: c++

I have:

```
typedef unsigned char;
std::vector<byte> data;
```

I tried to save data in file this way (but I have error):

```
fstream file(filename,ios::out);
file.write(&data, data.size());
```

How to process or cast *data* to write it in file.

Comment: This code is wrong - it won't compile.

Comment: data.size is a problem. Its not function so it shoudld be `data.size()`

Answer (score 9, accepted):

To store a vector in a file, you have to write the contents of the vector, not the vector itself. You can access the raw data with `&vector[0]`, address of the first element (given it contains at least one element).

```
ofstream outfile(filename, ios::out | ios::binary); 
outfile.write(&data[0], data.size());
```

This should be fairly efficient at writing. `fstream` is generic, use `ofstream` if you are going to write.

Comment: Note, that with C++11 `&data[0]` may be replaced with `data.data()` which looks a little cleaner.

Comment: A cast is required - the first parameter of `istream::write` is `const char *`, however in OP code, `&data[0]` is `unsigned char *`

Answer (score 5):

*Statement `file.write(&buffer[0],buffer.size())` makes error:

> error C2664: 'std::basic_ostream<_Elem,_Traits>::write' : cannot
>   convert parameter 1 from 'unsigned char *' to 'const char *'

*In my compiler (VS2008) I don't have data() method for vector.

I think below is correct:

```
file.write((const char*)&buffer[0],buffer.size());
```

Comment: You use it like this `file.write(reinterpret_cast<const char*>(&myVector[0]), myVector.size());`

Comment: data() method is there only in C++11 so in VS2008 it won't b there.

Comment: If you're going to cast, then why not cast to the type mentioned in the  error message?  Also, you only *think* it is correct?  Is it helpful to every future viewer of this question if an answer only thinks itself correct and hasn't actually verified it?  I'm not trying to put you down; just trying to improve the answer.

Comment: @Kaz Dragon: So write your answer and my alternative version and I will accept it. I corrected my answer.

Comment: Actually, hadn't noticed that you're also the question poster.  You can disregard half of what I said.

Comment: It would have been helpful to know in the beginning what IDE you were using.

Answer (score 3):

Use [vector::data](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/vector/vector/data/) to get a pointer the the underlying data:

```
file.write(data.data(), data.size());
```

Comment: With this approach one should point out, that the latter argument represents the number of bytes to be written. As `sizeof(char) == 1` this is ok. For any other datatype use `file.write((char*) data.data(), data.size() * sizeof(data.front()))`. As @staticx pointed out, make sure to add the appropriate flags when opening the ofstream: `ofstream file(filename, ios::out | ios::binary);`

Answer (score 2):

You are to pass the address of the first element, not the address of the vector object itself.

```
     &data[0]
```

Note: Make sure that the vector is not empty before doing this.

Answer (score 2):

A lot of these solutions are only partially complete (lacking includes & casts), so let me post a full working example:

```
#include <vector>
#include <fstream>

int main()
{
    std::vector<std::byte> dataVector(10, std::byte{ 'Z' });

    const std::string filename = "C:\\test_file.txt";

    std::ofstream outfile(filename, std::ios::out | std::ios::binary);
    outfile.write(reinterpret_cast<const char*>(dataVector.data()), dataVector.size());

    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think that ostream.write (myVector[0], ...) will not work, as it does not work in reading into vector (that I had.)
What works is ostream.write(MyVector.data(), ...)
Note: for reading use ifstream.read(const_cast(MyVector.data()), ...)